# редактирование табличных данных в браузере

Tags: python, django

Всем добрый день!
Нужна подсказка опытных людей.
Есть база данных телефонных номеров с кучей полей. Вывести данные из БД  на страницу я могу без проблем. Но встает вопрос редактирования данных - хочу чтобы пользователю была доступна возможность редактировать табличные данные как в Microsoft Excel (просто провалившись в ячейку). Думаю, что средствами django тут не обойтись. Посоветуйте куда копать - нужен небольшой гайд.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужна библиотека UpdateView из django.views.generic.
Она позволит вывести в браузер данные из БД и дать возможность их редактирования.

Выглядит так

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView, UpdateView, DeleteView


class YourUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = YourModel
    template_name = 'your_template.html'
    form_class = YourModelForm
```